# Make C# Unity Script database methods more re-usable and concise

Tags: c#, database, unity3d

I have a C# file, that makes some modifications on screen (changes the text on the user interface) but I have some doubts:

- How I can re-use the below methods to be more concise and reusable?
- How I can separate the database methods in another file class?

```
private void GetDoencaNome(){
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
        dbConnection.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT nome FROM doenca WHERE id=@id";
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                while(reader.Read()){
                    doenca.nome = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void GetDoencaDescricao(){
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
        dbConnection.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT descricao FROM descricao_doenca WHERE id=@id";
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                while(reader.Read()){
                    doenca.descricao = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void GetDoencaSintomasIds(){
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
        dbConnection.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT sintoma_id FROM doenca_sintoma WHERE doenca_id=@id";
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                while(reader.Read()){
                    listaIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void GetDoencaSintomas(){
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
        dbConnection.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT descricao FROM sintoma WHERE";
            sqlQuery += " id=" + listaIds[0].ToString();
            for(int i = 1; i < listaIds.Count; i++){
                sqlQuery += " OR id=" + listaIds[i].ToString();
            }
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                while(reader.Read()){
                    doenca.sintomas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your title to say, shortly, what problem your scipt is solving. That will help make your title more distinctive. Thanks!

Comment: I have rolled back your question. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Quill my revision not change the question and if I need post another question with my update the question will be closed by duplicate

Comment: An updated version of your code will not be closed as a duplicate. Please don't update your question with your updated code, this invalidates the answers

Comment: @Quill You can rolled back to earlier version of my question?

Comment: I rolled back your question to before you posted the update, yes.

Comment: @Quill I need to put the update in my question

Comment: Please don't update your question with your code updates. Feel free to add them as an answer so long as you review your code and it's not a code dump. Or you can add a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General

**Good**

Except for the non english part you are naming your methods and variables in a good way using the correct casing style.

You are using `using` statements to properly dispose the `IDisposable`'s which is the way to go.

You are coding against interfaces rather then concrete implementations which is the way to go as well.

**Not so good**

You are using methods `GetXXX` but the methods returning type is `void`. If one read `GetXXX` or `FetchXXX` one expect that the method is in fact returning something.

#### Your "problem"

The first two methods are doing basically the same. They open a connection to a database, executing a `SQL` statement and using the value of the first column which is read by the reader as a `string`.

The easiest way would be to pass the `SQL` statement and the `ID` to a method which returns the read string which then can be assigned to the desired property of the `doenca` (whatever that is).

---

Because usually an `ID` is unique I expect that query will only return one item, so you should use [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of having the `while(reader.Read())` loop.

This could look like so

```
private string ExecuteScalar(string sqlQuery, string id)
{
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", id));
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            return ConvertFromDBVal<string>(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
}
```

where the [`ConvertFromDBVal<T>()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870771/2655508) is

```
public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
    {
        return default(T); // returns the default value for the type
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

now the assignment of that properties could look like so

```
doenca.nome = ExecuteScalar("SELECT nome FROM doenca WHERE id = @id",  doencaId);  
doenca.descricao = ExecuteScalar("SELECT descricao FROM descricao_doenca WHERE id = @id", doencaId);
```

If you want to hide that implementation you could add two more methods like so

```
private string FetchNomeById(string id)
{
    return ExecuteScalar("SELECT nome FROM doenca WHERE id = @id",  id);  
}
private string FetchDescricaoById(string id)
{
    return ExecuteScalar("SELECT descricao FROM descricao_doenca WHERE id = @id",  id);  
}
```

which results in assigning the properties like so

```
doenca.nome = FetchNomeById(doencaId);
doenca.descricao = FetchDescricaoById(doencaId);
```

but I would like to encourage you to use english for naming classes, methods and variables, because if **Sam the maintainer** isn't familiar with your language he/she will at least speak english because thats just what each developer does, so it would be easier for **Sam** to get what your code is about.

---

The second two methods are doing basically the same as well.  They open a connection to a database, executing a SQL statement and using the values of the first column. The difference is that they "return" different types so this is screaming for a generic version like so

```
private IList<T> FetchValuesOfSingleColumn<T>(string sql, string condition)
{
    IList<T> values = new List<T>();

    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sqlQuery = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(condition)
                            ? sql
                            : sql + " WHERE " + condition;
           
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using (IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(ConvertFromDBVal<T>(reader[0]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

which can be used to get all values from a single column **without** a condition as well.

Assuming `doenca.sintomas` is a `List<string>` the usage could of that method could then look like so

```
string condition = 
IList<string> descratios = FetchValuesOfSingleColumn<string>("SELECT descricao FROM sintoma", condition);

doeanca.sintomas.AddRange(descratios);
```

where `condition` could be constructed like so

```
private string BuildCondition<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, string columnName, string @operator, string conditionType)
{
    IList<T> items = values.ToList();
    if (items.Count == 0) { return string.Empty; }
    if (conditionType==null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("conditionType)"); }
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(conditionType)) { throw new ArgumentException("parameter may not be empty", "conditionType"); }

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    string format = columnName + @operator + "{0}";
    string conditionTypeFormat = " " + conditionType + " " + format;

    builder.AppendFormat(format, items[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat(conditionTypeFormat, items[i]);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

resulting in

```
string condition = BuildCondition<int>(listaIds, "id", "=","OR");
IList<string> descratios = FetchValuesOfSingleColumn<string>("SELECT descricao FROM sintoma", condition);  
doeanca.sintomas.AddRange(descratios);
```

and for the other property assignment

```
string condition = BuildCondition<int>(new int[]{ doencaId }, "id", "=","OR");
IList<int> descratios = FetchValuesOfSingleColumn<int>("SELECT sintoma_id FROM doenca_sintoma", condition);  
listaIds.AddRange(descratios);
```

The `BuildCondition<T>()` method will only work correctly with `T` being a numeric types because this types won't need quotes for the query.

---

If you need more queries with datamappings I would like to encourage you to dig into some object relational framework like for instance [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or any [other relational mapping framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software).

Comment: Heslacher the method `GetDoencaSintomas()` has different structure, how I can re-use ?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Heslacher, until this moment your answer is the best, but when was implementing another method I had problems with your solution, you can check it? is below [ UPDATE ] in my question. (I put in pastebin because my question was rolled back http://pastebin.com/Vn0acTfg)

Comment: I can do this but unfortunately I will won't be in the office till monday.

Comment: You can't do the query of the link with the provided code. Thats where the last paragraph of my answer comes into play. You should use some relational data mapping framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have each method `return` the retrieved data value(s) instead of setting properties directly.

Either make each method `public` or have the owing class call these methods from public methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to radarbob's suggestion. You make a static database class that returns the results. Your above code would become the first block below. Otherwise this seems like the standard C# SQL pattern and I don't see anything you need to fix.

```
private void GetDoencaNome(){
    doenca.descricao = Database.GetDoencaDescricao(doencaId);
}

private void GetDoencaDescricao(){

    doenca.descricao = Database.GetDoencaDescricao(doencaId);

}

private void GetDoencaSintomasIds(){

    listaIds = Database.GetDoencaSintomasIds(doencaId);

}

private void GetDoencaSintomas(){

    doenca.sintomas = Database.GetDoencaSintomas(listaIds)

}
```

The database class:

```
public static class Database {
    public static string GetDoencaNome(int doencaId){
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT nome FROM doenca WHERE id=@id";
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        return reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetDoencaDescricao(int doencaId){
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT descricao FROM descricao_doenca WHERE id=@id";
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        return reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<int> GetDoencaSintomasIds(int doencaId){
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT sintoma_id FROM doenca_sintoma WHERE doenca_id=@id";
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@id", doencaId));
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        ids.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                    }
                    return ids;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GetDoencaSintomas(List<int> listaIds){
        List<string> doencasintomas = List<string>();
        using(IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)){
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()){
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT descricao FROM sintoma WHERE";
                sqlQuery += " id=" + listaIds[0].ToString();
                for(int i = 1; i < listaIds.Count; i++){
                    sqlQuery += " OR id=" + listaIds[i].ToString();
                }
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using(IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                    while(reader.Read()){
                        doencasintomas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    return doencasintomas;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```